# Custom navbar color when hovering under Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I fail to find the right CSS syntax to custom my navbar links when hovering. My navbar is as follows:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account | <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "User", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Update", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
        </ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Logout", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
```

I manage to get the correct hovering effect on the dropdown menu with

```
.dropdown:hover {
background:#3b3535;
color: #ece6e6;
}
```

I want to have the same effect on my links "Home" and "Logout". I tried

```
.navbar-nav:hover {
background:#3b3535;
color: #ece6e6;
}
```

but the three links ("Home", "Account" and "logout") get hovered at once. Since then I have tried numerous options including:

```
.ul#navbar-nav a:hover {
background:#3b3535;
color: #ece6e6;
}

.navbar-nav ul.nav li:hover a{
background:#3b3535;
color: #ece6e6;
}

.ul.nav li a:hover {
background:#3b3535;
color: #ece6e6;
}
```

but none of them seems to work. Could you give me the appropriate syntax to have the correct hovering effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no link `<a>` for Home and Logout so just use the below for targeting them both.

```
ul.nav li:hover {
  background:#3b3535;
  color: #ece6e6;
}
```

And `ul` is not a class to have a dot before the selector :)